# MySQL character set similar to Oracle "WE8MSWIN1252" character set

Tags: mysql, database, character-encoding, case-sensitive

Can someone please tell me a character set in MySQL which is similar to the Oracle's default character set "WE8MSWIN1252" ?

Please note that it should be also a case-sensitive character set. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As the name implies, WE8MSWIN1252 is based on Microsoft Windows 1252. So is MySQL's latin1 character set. So: latin1 is similar. There is no such thing as a "case-sensitive character set", but you can pick a case-sensitive collation for latin1, such as latin1_bin.